# Talend warning and error messages are black

Tags: linux, talend

When I was using Talend on Windows, I could see warning and error messages.
Now that I am using Talend on Linux, all I can see is black rectangles.

Do I need to embedded or install missing java libraries? If so, how do I find those missing?

Here are what I am using:

- Ubuntu 17-04
- Talend Open Studio for Big Data
- Openjdk 1.8.0_131

**Edit**
Here is a capture of the black rectangle when I hover the warning sign on one of my table.
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Please [edit] your question and add screenshots.

Comment: Its not clear to me if this is a programming or development question. Perhaps you should add your misbehaving code to ally the concerns. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's not the code that generate the problem. My colleague runs it on Mac and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be connected to your desktop engine (KDE / Gnome) and Eclipse.

See the answers from this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse to check out how you can resolve the issue.